# How to monitor a deadlock in DB2

Tags: db2, deadlock, aix, db2-luw

I am following this link and try to simulate the deadlock issue:

http://www.dba-db2.com/2012/06/how-to-monitor-a-deadlock-in-db2.html

I can see my command run successful.

After that I go to simulate a deadlock error through `DbVisualiser` tool. However I didnt see any file being generated to the path.

Can someone point the mistake to me?

And also, I try to read back those old 0000000.evt file, it show me something as follow:

```
                            EVENT LOG HEADER
  Event Monitor name: DB2DETAILDEADLOCK
  Server Product ID: SQL10059
  Version of event monitor data: 12
  Byte order: BIG ENDIAN
  Number of nodes in db2 instance: 1
  Codepage of database: 1208
  Territory code of database: 1
  Server instance name: db2inst1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Database Name: MYDB   
  Database Path: /db2home/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00003/MEMBER0000/
  First connection timestamp: 01/29/2018 10:00:17.694784
  Event Monitor Start time:   01/29/2018 10:00:18.951331
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Database Name: MYDB   
  Database Path: /db2home/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00003/MEMBER0000/
  First connection timestamp: 01/29/2018 10:12:54.382936
  Event Monitor Start time:   01/29/2018 10:12:54.697223
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This means no deadlock?

Comment: Yes that means no deadlock. If there *was* a deadlock and the event monitor was active at the time, then you should see a "Deadlock Event" stanza in the db2evmon output.  You can also use the monitoring functions to confirm if a deadlock happened (but not how it happened).  The following query reports cumulative values since database-activation: `SELECT deadlocks, lock_timeouts  FROM TABLE (MON_GET_DATABASE(-2));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works correctly for me (linux, Db2 v11.1). Here are some command lines with annotations. You need to have suitable authorisation/privilege for each command. I was using the instance owner account.

Disable default db2detaildeadlock monitor first and then create your own:

```
$ db2 "set event monitor db2detaildeadlock state=0"      
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ 
$ db2 "create event monitor dlmon for deadlocks write to file '/tmp'"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$
$ db2 "set event monitor dlmon state=1"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$
```

Generate a deadlock, ensure you see this SQLCODE -911 with reason code 2.
If you dont' see the reason code 2 then you *don't* have any deadlock but you might have a timeout and timeouts don't get recorded in the deadlock monitor.

Here I show the victim of the deadlock getting notified of rollback and you can see the correct reason code:

```
$ db2 +c "select * from db2inst1.dlk where a=4 with rr"
SQL0911N  The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock 
or timeout.  Reason code "2".  SQLSTATE=40001
```

Investigate the monitor output with db2evmon and view resulting file

```
$ db2evmon -db mydb -evm dlmon > /tmp/db2evmon.dlmon.1

Reading /tmp/00000000.evt ...

$ view /tmp/db2evmon.dlmon.1
...<snip>
...
3) Deadlock Event ...
  Deadlock ID:   2
  Number of applications deadlocked: 2
  Deadlock detection time: 01/03/2018 09:06:39.019854
  Rolled back Appl participant no: 2
  Rolled back Appl Id: *LOCAL.db2inst1.180301090546
  Rolled back Appl seq number: 00001
  Rolled back Appl handle: 11872

...<snip>
```

Comment: Hi @mao, so the 0000000.evt is actually the deadlock log? I am actually still not sure what is the deadlock file name. I have add something in my question, I tried to read those old 0000000.evt, but it didnt show anything related to deadlock, i thought its not the deadlock log.

Comment: You don't need to look at actual filenames (they can vary), if you use the *exact* commands shown to db2evmon command.  Show your proof that a deadlock (-911 reason code 2) really did happen.

Comment: Hi @mao, another thing is, I have a lot of path that store the db2detaildeadlock log file, for example, `/db2home/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/MEMBER0000/db2event/db2detaildeadlock`, `/db2home/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00002/MEMBER0000/db2event/db2detaildeadlock`, `/db2home/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00003/MEMBER0000/db2event/db2detaildeadlock` and so on. And there are `SQL00004`, `SQL00005` and so on. May I know how to know my log is  log at which folder? Because its from production, I have to ask IT to retrieve the file for me.

Comment: @Panadol Chong : Consider upvoting or marking answers as correct when people help you. Don't ask new questions in comment threads, instead create a new question.